# Why td size is different in some condition

Tags: html, css

When I try to make html tables, I wonder why

1. `td`size is different between filled cells and others.Does this come
   from `padding`?
2. How to set to same size in each cells even if any content will be
   filled?

If someone experienced same issue,please let me know. Thanks

```css
td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td>1</td>
  <td></td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table has no fixed width, so the cells inside will only take up the space that their content requires.

If your table has a fixed width however, you can use [`table-layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) to ensure all of the cells remain the same size:

Note also that you are missing required markup from your table:

```css
table{
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 10rem;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
};
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```